# Change header template from Divi theme

Tags: wordpress, divi-theme

I have this template(header.php). Now i'm working on a site, and i want to to some changes in this template. According to this template i get 2 menu locations, but i want to change the order of them.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php
 elegant_description();
 elegant_keywords();
 elegant_canonical();
 /**
  * Fires in the head, before {@see wp_head()} is called. This action can be used to
  * insert elements into the beginning of the head before any styles or scripts.
  *
  * @since 1.0
  */
 do_action( 'et_head_meta' );
 $template_directory_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
?>

 <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.documentElement.className = 'js';
 </script>

 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php
 $product_tour_enabled = et_builder_is_product_tour_enabled();
 $page_container_style = $product_tour_enabled ? ' style="padding-top: 0px;"' : ''; ?>
 <div id="page-container"<?php echo et_core_intentionally_unescaped( $page_container_style, 'fixed_string' ); ?>>
<?php
 if ( $product_tour_enabled || is_page_template( 'page-template-blank.php' ) ) {
  return;
 }
 $et_secondary_nav_items = et_divi_get_top_nav_items();
 $et_phone_number = $et_secondary_nav_items->phone_number;
 $et_email = $et_secondary_nav_items->email;
 $et_contact_info_defined = $et_secondary_nav_items->contact_info_defined;
 $show_header_social_icons = $et_secondary_nav_items->show_header_social_icons;
 $et_secondary_nav = $et_secondary_nav_items->secondary_nav;
 $et_top_info_defined = $et_secondary_nav_items->top_info_defined;
 $et_slide_header = 'slide' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) || 'fullscreen' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ? true : false;
?>

 <?php if ( $et_top_info_defined && ! $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
  <?php ob_start(); ?>
  <div id="top-header"<?php echo $et_top_info_defined ? '' : 'style="display: none;"'; ?>>
   <div class="container clearfix">

   <?php if ( $et_contact_info_defined ) : ?>

    <div id="et-info">
    <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_phone_number = et_get_option( 'phone_number' ) ) ) : ?>
     <span id="et-info-phone"><?php echo et_core_esc_previously( et_sanitize_html_input_text( $et_phone_number ) ); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_email = et_get_option( 'header_email' ) ) ) : ?>
     <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( 'mailto:' . $et_email ); ?>"><span id="et-info-email"><?php echo esc_html( $et_email ); ?></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    if ( true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
     get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
    } ?>
    </div> <!-- #et-info -->

   <?php endif; // true === $et_contact_info_defined ?>

    <div id="et-secondary-menu">
    <?php
     if ( ! $et_contact_info_defined && true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
      get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
     } else if ( $et_contact_info_defined && true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
      ob_start();
      get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
      $duplicate_social_icons = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      printf(
       '<div class="et_duplicate_social_icons">
        %1$s
       </div>',
       et_core_esc_previously( $duplicate_social_icons )
      );
     }
     if ( '' !== $et_secondary_nav ) {
      echo et_core_esc_wp( $et_secondary_nav );
     }
     et_show_cart_total();
    ?>
    </div> <!-- #et-secondary-menu -->

   </div> <!-- .container -->
  </div> <!-- #top-header -->
 <?php
  $top_header = ob_get_clean();
  /**
   * Filters the HTML output for the top header.
   *
   * @since 3.10
   *
   * @param string $top_header
   */
  echo et_core_intentionally_unescaped( apply_filters( 'et_html_top_header', $top_header ), 'html' );
 ?>
 <?php endif; // true ==== $et_top_info_defined ?>

 <?php if ( $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
  <?php ob_start(); ?>
  <div class="et_slide_in_menu_container">
   <?php if ( 'fullscreen' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) || is_customize_preview() ) { ?>
    <span class="mobile_menu_bar et_toggle_fullscreen_menu"></span>
   <?php } ?>

   <?php
    if ( $et_contact_info_defined || true === $show_header_social_icons || false !== et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', true ) || class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) || is_customize_preview() ) { ?>
     <div class="et_slide_menu_top">

     <?php if ( 'fullscreen' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ) { ?>
      <div class="et_pb_top_menu_inner">
     <?php } ?>
   <?php }
    if ( true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
     get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
    }
    et_show_cart_total();
   ?>
   <?php if ( false !== et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', true ) || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
    <?php if ( 'fullscreen' !== et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ) { ?>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
     <?php
      printf( '<input type="search" class="et-search-field" placeholder="%1$s" value="%2$s" name="s" title="%3$s" />',
       esc_attr__( 'Search &hellip;', 'Divi' ),
       get_search_query(),
       esc_attr__( 'Search for:', 'Divi' )
      );
     ?>
     <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit_header"></button>
    </form>
   <?php endif; // true === et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', false ) ?>

   <?php if ( $et_contact_info_defined ) : ?>

    <div id="et-info">
    <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_phone_number = et_get_option( 'phone_number' ) ) ) : ?>
     <span id="et-info-phone"><?php echo et_core_esc_previously( et_sanitize_html_input_text( $et_phone_number ) ); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_email = et_get_option( 'header_email' ) ) ) : ?>
     <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( 'mailto:' . $et_email ); ?>"><span id="et-info-email"><?php echo esc_html( $et_email ); ?></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div> <!-- #et-info -->

   <?php endif; // true === $et_contact_info_defined ?>
   <?php if ( $et_contact_info_defined || true === $show_header_social_icons || false !== et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', true ) || class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) || is_customize_preview() ) { ?>
    <?php if ( 'fullscreen' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ) { ?>
     </div> <!-- .et_pb_top_menu_inner -->
    <?php } ?>

    </div> <!-- .et_slide_menu_top -->
   <?php } ?>

   <div class="et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container">
    <?php
     $slide_nav = '';
     $slide_menu_class = 'et_mobile_menu';
     $slide_nav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'echo' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) );
     $slide_nav .= wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'echo' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) );
    ?>

    <ul id="mobile_menu_slide" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $slide_menu_class ); ?>">

    <?php
     if ( '' === $slide_nav ) :
    ?>
      <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_home_link' ) ) { ?>
       <li <?php if ( is_home() ) echo( 'class="current_page_item"' ); ?>><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Home', 'Divi' ); ?></a></li>
      <?php }; ?>

      <?php show_page_menu( $slide_menu_class, false, false ); ?>
      <?php show_categories_menu( $slide_menu_class, false ); ?>
    <?php
     else :
      echo et_core_esc_wp( $slide_nav ) ;
     endif;
    ?>

    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php
  $slide_header = ob_get_clean();
  /**
   * Filters the HTML output for the slide header.
   *
   * @since 3.10
   *
   * @param string $top_header
   */
  echo et_core_intentionally_unescaped( apply_filters( 'et_html_slide_header', $slide_header ), 'html' );
 ?>
 <?php endif; // true ==== $et_slide_header ?>

 <?php ob_start(); ?>
  <header id="main-header" data-height-onload="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'menu_height', '66' ) ); ?>">
   <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
   <?php
    $logo = ( $user_logo = et_get_option( 'divi_logo' ) ) && ! empty( $user_logo )
     ? $user_logo
     : $template_directory_uri . '/images/logo.png';
    ob_start();
   ?>
    <div class="logo_container">
     <span class="logo_helper"></span>
     <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" id="logo" data-height-percentage="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'logo_height', '54' ) ); ?>" />
     </a>
    </div>
   <?php
    $logo_container = ob_get_clean();
    /**
     * Filters the HTML output for the logo container.
     *
     * @since 3.10
     *
     * @param string $logo_container
     */
    echo et_core_intentionally_unescaped( apply_filters( 'et_html_logo_container', $logo_container ), 'html' );
   ?>
    <div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'menu_height', '66' ) ); ?>" data-fixed-height="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'minimized_menu_height', '40' ) ); ?>">
     <?php if ( ! $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
      <nav id="top-menu-nav">
      <?php
       $menuClass = 'nav';
       if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_disable_toptier' ) ) $menuClass .= ' et_disable_top_tier';
       $primaryNav = '';
       $primaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass, 'menu_id' => 'top-menu', 'echo' => false ) );
       if ( empty( $primaryNav ) ) :
      ?>
       <ul id="top-menu" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $menuClass ); ?>">
        <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_home_link' ) ) { ?>
         <li <?php if ( is_home() ) echo( 'class="current_page_item"' ); ?>><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Home', 'Divi' ); ?></a></li>
        <?php }; ?>

        <?php show_page_menu( $menuClass, false, false ); ?>
        <?php show_categories_menu( $menuClass, false ); ?>
       </ul>
      <?php
       else :
        echo et_core_esc_wp( $primaryNav );
       endif;
      ?>
      </nav>
     <?php endif; ?>

     <?php
     if ( ! $et_top_info_defined && ( ! $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) ) {
      et_show_cart_total( array(
       'no_text' => true,
      ) );
     }
     ?>

     <?php if ( $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
      <span class="mobile_menu_bar et_pb_header_toggle et_toggle_<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ); ?>_menu"></span>
     <?php endif; ?>

     <?php if ( ( false !== et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', true ) && ! $et_slide_header ) || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
     <div id="et_top_search">
      <span id="et_search_icon"></span>
     </div>
     <?php endif; // true === et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', false ) ?>

     <?php
     /**
      * Fires at the end of the 'et-top-navigation' element, just before its closing tag.
      *
      * @since 1.0
      */
     do_action( 'et_header_top' );
     ?>
    </div> <!-- #et-top-navigation -->
   </div> <!-- .container -->
   <div class="et_search_outer">
    <div class="container et_search_form_container">
     <form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
     <?php
      printf( '<input type="search" class="et-search-field" placeholder="%1$s" value="%2$s" name="s" title="%3$s" />',
       esc_attr__( 'Search &hellip;', 'Divi' ),
       get_search_query(),
       esc_attr__( 'Search for:', 'Divi' )
      );
     ?>
     </form>
     <span class="et_close_search_field"></span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header> <!-- #main-header -->
 <?php
  $main_header = ob_get_clean();
  /**
   * Filters the HTML output for the main header.
   *
   * @since 3.10
   *
   * @param string $main_header
   */
  echo et_core_intentionally_unescaped( apply_filters( 'et_html_main_header', $main_header ), 'html' );
 ?>
  <div id="et-main-area">
 <?php
  /**
   * Fires after the header, before the main content is output.
   *
   * @since 3.10
   */
  do_action( 'et_before_main_content' );
```

In practice the secondary menu appears first, before primary menu. How to change the ordering for displaying:
FIRST: Primary menu;
SECOND: Secondary menu;
Who knows how could i change the order, for displaying the same order that i described above?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not advisable to change the order of the menu in the DIVI theme. Just rearranging the code will collapse the header. 
So it is better to register a new Navigation Menu and then use it where you wanted.

Before making any changes to the theme files, make sure you are using Divi Child Theme. If you don't have one, You can download it here ([Divi Child Theme Download Link](https://www.divithemeexamples.com/bare-bones-divi-child-theme/))

Then you can copy your header.php file from Divi theme folder and paste it into the Child theme folder.

To register a custom menu, use the below code in the Functions.php file.

```
    function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
      register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```

Now go to Appearance -> Menus and create a New Menu and assign it as "My Custom Menu".

To add this menu to the header, Add the below code in header.php where you want to display the menu.

```
 'my-custom-menu', 
        'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 

?>
```

Then you can use the .custom_menu_class CSS class to style the menu.